# Pass a Javascript Object to an HTML iframe (as an Object)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, scope, arguments

A MainWindow creates a JavaScript object that the ChildWindow needs to utilize utilize.

My MainWindow.html looks like this at the moment

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      var varObject = {type:"Error", message:"Lots"};
    </script>
    <iframe class="child" src="ChildWindow.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

The ChildWindow.html looks like this

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      console.log(varObject.type); // goal is to log "Error"
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The ChildWindow is trying to use the object that was created in the MainWindow which of course it can't because I don't yet know how to pass it.

I've tried to Google this but most of the solutions I found involved passing the values as strings instead of as a variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One can simply pass the object by assigning the object to the `window` of the iframe.

*in the parent window:*

```
var frame = document.querySelector("iframe");
frame.contentWindow.object_of_interest = object_of_interest;
```

*in the iframe'ed window*

```js
console.log(window.object_of_interest);
```

Comment: Must be contentWindow instead contextWindow?

Comment: Worked for me with contentWindow, as @abdolence suggested.

Comment: SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "object_of_interest" on cross-origin object

Comment: @Oram - the "website" in the iframe must allow cross-origin access (or have the same origin) in order for you to modify its data. There are lots of security risks that could be exploited if browsers let users open other websites and modify the data in those websites with no restrictions.

Comment: I added the comment because you can't "_simply pass the object_". You have restrictions as you mentioned in your reply.

Answer (score 6):

Please have a look at following code :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      var varObject = {type:"Error", message:"Lots"};
      var child = document.getElementsByClassName("child")[0];
      var childWindow = child.contentWindow;
      childWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(varObject),*);
    </script>
    <iframe class="child" src="ChildWindow.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

In ChildWindow.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      function getData(e){
        let data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log(data);
      }
      if(window.addEventListener){
        window.addEventListener("message", getData, false);
      } else {
        window.attachEvent("onmessage", getData);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the complete example  

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to send messages to and from iFrames embedded in your site.

Comment: It's not necessarily going to be a message, sometimes it will be database connection objects

Comment: You can use `JSON.stringify(obj)` to convert your objects to strings and `JSON.parse(str)` to convert them back again.

Comment: This does not work if the object is a promise or a function or any other more complex object structure.